# using tkinter.Canvas.after

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make 2d game using tkinter, but faced the problem: instead of starting act2() after act() end, act2() and act() executes at the same time.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

can = tk.Canvas(height=500, width=1000)
can.pack()

rect = can.create_rectangle(0, 240, 20, 260, fil='#5F6A6A')


def act():
    global rect, can
    pos = can.coords(rect)
    if pos[2] < 1000:
        can.move(rect, 5, 0)
        can.update()
        can.after(2, act)
        

def act2():
    global rect, can
    pos = can.coords(rect)
    if pos[3] < 500:
        can.move(rect, 0, 5)
        can.update()
        can.after(2, act2)
  

def key_down(key):
    act()
    act2()
    

can.bind("<Button-1>", key_down)
root.mainloop()
```

How can I set order of methods executing?

Comment: _"act2() and act() executes at the same time."_ that's impossible. tkinter is single-threaded. Only one function can run at a time.

Comment: Instead of moving to the right side and than to bottom, rectangle moves diagonally - I meant that, when said "executes at the same time."

Comment: Do you realize it happens at the same time because `after()` doesnt block the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `can.after(1, act)` is non-blocking and doesn't call `act()` and wait for it to finish before moving onto the next line of code - it instead schedules it to be called later, then immediately moves on to the next line of code. This means that in `key_down`, when you call `act()` then `act2()` it does not move your rectangle all the way to the right then all the way down, but interleaves moving it right and down. In order to wait for the rectangle to move all the way right before starting moving it down, schedule `act2()` after `act()` has finished by using the `else` of the existing `if` statement:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

root = tk.Tk()

can = tk.Canvas(height=500, width=1000)
can.pack()

rect = can.create_rectangle(0, 240, 20, 260, fil='#5F6A6A')


def act():
    global rect, can
    pos = can.coords(rect)
    if pos[2] < 1000:
        can.move(rect, 5, 0)
        can.update()
        can.after(1, act)
    else:
        can.after(1, act2)
        

def act2():
    global rect, can
    pos = can.coords(rect)
    if pos[3] < 500:
        can.move(rect, 0, 5)
        can.update()
        can.after(1, act2)
  

def key_down(key):
    act()
    

can.bind("<Button-1>", key_down)
root.mainloop()
```

If you would prefer to keep your code looking sequential, you could use an approach with generators, and a scheduler, such as this: https://pastebin.com/H6meR3q1

Comment: Why the delay in the `else`? `act2()` seems fine.

Comment: @CoolCloud It depends if you want delay or not. Either option is fine.